# std::promise::get_future raises illegal instruction (SIGILL)

Tags: c++, promise, future, googletest

This very basic example:

```
std::promise<int> p;
std::future<int> f = p.get_future();
```

raises an illegal instruction signal (SIGILL). The signal originates from  line 463:

```
__throw_future_error((int)future_errc::no_state);
```

Why and how can I fix this? I found the very same example on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Background: In one of my tests (I use Googletest), I want to check if a method call terminates. Since the framework doesn't provide any mechanisms for this, my idea was something like this:

```
std::promise<bool> p;
std::future<bool> f = p.get_future();
std::thread([](std::promise<bool>& finished, Foo*& foo) {
    foo->bar();
    p.set_value(true);
}, std::ref(p), std::ref(foo)).detach();

EXPECT_NE(std::future_status::timeout, f.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000)));
```

Comment: You should dive into your debugger and figure out which instruction it is by looking at the disassembly. Only then we can tell more. It may be the same reason why windows 8.1 won't work on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you time out or set the value, you have a race condition between `p` being destroyed and its use in the lambda.

In case of value setting, the race condition could be avoided by using `set_value_at_thread_exit`, but that won't solve the first problem. In fact, you *cannot* fully solve the first problem, because that thread will leak and hang if the function doesn't return, and threads don't give you an option to avoid that.

You can mitigate the problem by moving the promise (and probably all other objects that are used) into the thread constructor, instead of referencing them.